# Recursion in Java without use of global variables

Tags: java, recursion

i am having problem with using recursion in java without use of static variable, I cannot structure the recursive calls according to the return type of function. For example: This is a code for in order traversal of tree that i wrote, but it only returns only one element, I need to know what i am doing wrong and how can I correct it.

```
 Code:

        public List<Integer> inorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
            List<Integer> ls = new LinkedList<Integer>();
            if(root!=null)
            {
                inorderTraversal(root.left);
                ls.add(root.val);
                inorderTraversal(root.right);
            }

            return ls;
        }
If I try to write it this way, I get an error <Identifier Expected>
Code2:
    public void inorderTraversal(TreeNode root, ls)
          {
              if(root!=null)
              {
                  inorderTraversal(root.left,ls);
                  ls.add(root.val);
                  inorderTraversal(root.right,ls);
                }

              }

   public List<Integer> inorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
    List<Integer> ls=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    inorderTraversal(root,ls);

    return ls;     

    }
    }
```

Comment: One blank line is more than enough, unless your goal is to make your code as hard to read as possible.

Comment: Sorry i just copied it from the online compiler where i have been doing this

Answer (score 4):

Pass the result list in as an argument:

```
public void inorderTraversal(TreeNode root, List<Integer> ls) {
    if(root!=null)
    {
        inorderTraversal(root.left, ls);
        ls.add(root.val);
        inorderTraversal(root.right, ls);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't java pass the argument by value so how can I expect that same list will be appended?

Comment: Java is pass-by-value but there's a subtlety.  For objects, Java passes the _object reference_ by value.  This is a slightly tricky part if you come from languages where objects can live on the stack.  In Java ALL objects live on the heap and the variables designating them are all references.